# How to protect critical financial information in Web Apps and Web Services? (examples, common approaches)

Tags: databases, financial

Let's imagine a web service that allows to create wallets, deposit money and cryptocurrencies, perform money and cryptocurrency exchange and withdraw money.

The critical information here is:

1. "sign in" credentials that allows to sign in to account.
2. Private keys that allows to interact with cryptocurrencies wallets.

The common security questions here are:

1. Authorization and Authentication mechanism.
2. Where to store private keys and how to access them from back-end application.
3. Financial transaction confirmation.

We must be tolerant to the following situations:

1. Villain stole the account's credentials (possible for Admin account).
2. Villain obtained access to the host where back-end application is running.

In all cases money still must be save.

So, are there common approaches or examples of architectures for such systems. Maybe useful articles?